# What is the difference between 賛成 and 支持?

Tags: word-choice

differnce between 賛成(さんせい) and 支持(しじ)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

## Intro

---

Although both terms can be used to describe that someone is in favor of something, there is a slight difference in nuance.

You can think of 賛成 as "Agree" and "Approve", while 支持 is closer to "backing" and "supporting" meaning you are **willing to put an effort to support the case (you don't **simply** agree with it)**

Let the following sentences act as a guide:

### 賛成

---

> 彼女が賛成するかどうか、明らかではない。
> Whether she will agree or not is not clear.

or the common saying (at least in English):

> 僕は君の意見に不賛成だがそれを述べる君の権利は最後まで護ってやろう。
> I disapprove of what you say, but I will defend to the death your right to say it.
> 不賛成 meaning "disagree/disapprove" from the combination of 不 and 賛成

Also note that 賛成, can be used as a **single word reply**:

> 「賛成！」（私もその意見に賛成です。）

which gets translated as “I agree!” or even just “agreed!

### 支持

---

> 私は君を支持します。
> I'll stand up for you.

and:

> 彼は民主党の支持者だ。
> He supports the Democratic Party.

支持者 meaning "supporter" from the combination of 支持 and 者

Comment: `護てやろう` -- Is it read まもってやろう ? `or the supper common saying:` -- What does this "supper" mean?

Comment: Is it read まもってやろう  --> Yes. I also meant  to say "super", so "supper" was a typo :)